# Multiple auto-complete field with different values

Tags: php, autocomplete

I have two fields

```
<input type="text" id="user-name" />
<input type="text" id="admin-name" />


 $("#user-name").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
```

I'm using single php file handle autocomplete .i.e autocomplete.php

```
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY user_name";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['user_name']."\n";
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the expected output for username, but how to do same for admin-name with the same php file. as default autocomplete.php will fetch username only, how to make it to act different

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, passing two parameters to autocomplete, and pass q2 as the field you want
  $q1=$_GET['q1'];
  $q2 = $_GET['q2']

```
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE {$q2} LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY user_name";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['user_name']."\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I'm not going to deep use this js
var source = 'autocomplete.php?q1='+$("#user-name").val()+"&q2=user_name"
$("#user-name").autocomplete(source, {
        selectFirst: true
    });
var source2 = 'autocomplete.php?q1='+$("#admin-name").val()+"&q2=admin_name"
$("#user-name").autocomplete(source2, {
        selectFirst: true
    });

Comment: $("#user-name").val() is null, when do i need to cal this methods, on each keyup or document ready?

Comment: Use a test to change the parameter to check

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="admin-name" class="autofill" /> 

$("#user-name").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    }); /// here you used id selector so function call a unique id 

 $(".autofill").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    }); /// we use the class for multiple handlings 

i think it works. if not show me the error,
```

Comment: I know how to call multiple instance of autocomplete. How does the autocomplete.php act different for user-name & admin-name???/